# How to find RadioButtonList name,id,class(css attributes) which is present in content place holder using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages, contentplaceholder

Im using Master Page in my web forms project.I place below code in my content place holder.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="ckbLstPartner" runat="server" name="ckbLstPartner"
                                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
            CssClass="cssRdlstMoheSacm" Height="85px" Width="430px">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>

        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="trSetPartnerNamesAvailability" value="trSetPartnerNamesAvailability" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="trSetPartnerInfoAvailability" value="trSetPartnerInfoAvailability" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartnersName" value="txtPartnersName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtReqScoreCourseAccept" value="txtReqScoreCourseAccept" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCourseAcceptNote" value="txtCourseAcceptNote" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And im using javascript code to operate some functionality.

**JS CODE:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
            $('#<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>').change(function () {
                if ($("input[name='<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>'][value='1']").prop("checked")) {

                    $('#<%=trSetPartnerNamesAvailability.ClientID%>').show();
                    $('#<%=trSetPartnerInfoAvailability.ClientID%>').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('#<%=trSetPartnerNamesAvailability.ClientID%>').hide();
                    $('#<%=trSetPartnerInfoAvailability.ClientID%>').hide();
                    $('#<%= txtPartnersName.ClientID %>').val('');
                    $('#<%= txtReqScoreCourseAccept.ClientID %>').val('');
                    $('#<%= txtCourseAcceptNote.ClientID %>').val('');
                }
            });
        });
```

when i run the application the radio button list is converted as shown below

**Browser output:**

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ckbLstPartner" class="cssRdlstMoheSacm" style="height:85px;width:430px;">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ckbLstPartner_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ckbLstPartner" value="1" /><label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_ckbLstPartner_0">Yes</label></td><td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ckbLstPartner_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ckbLstPartner" value="0" /><label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_ckbLstPartner_1">No</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>

        <br />
        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$trSetPartnerNamesAvailability" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_trSetPartnerNamesAvailability" value="trSetPartnerNamesAvailability" />
        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$trSetPartnerInfoAvailability" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_trSetPartnerInfoAvailability" value="trSetPartnerInfoAvailability" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPartnersName" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPartnersName" value="txtPartnersName" />
        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtReqScoreCourseAccept" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtReqScoreCourseAccept" value="txtReqScoreCourseAccept" />
        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCourseAcceptNote" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCourseAcceptNote" value="txtCourseAcceptNote" />
        <br />
```

Because of this reason, my js code is not working(Particularly " `if ($("input[name='<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>'][value='1']").prop("checked")) {}`". It cannot be validated by if condition).So please help me how to find the name,id,class(css attribute) in javascript.

When i use the same logic in webforms with out using Master Page works fine.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Resolved this problem by using the below code:

```
 if ($("input[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ckbLstPartner'][value='1']").prop("checked")) {}
```

Comment: The appropriate answer is 
`$("input[name='<%=trSetPartnerNamesAvailability.UniqueID%>']:checked").val();`

Answer (score 0):

you can get value by .....

$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_trSetPartnerNamesAvailability").val();

Comment: hello muttu.i need to check  if ($("input[name='<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>'][value='1']").prop("checked")).How? based on this i need to show and hide controls.With out master page it works fine.when i place code in content place holder.it fails.

Comment: Hai Muttu i got Answer.Thanks For Follow up.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate answer is

`$("input[name='<%=ServerSideControlName.UniqueID%>']:checked").val();`

and in your case

`$("input[name='<%=trSetPartnerNamesAvailability.UniqueID%>']:checked").val();`